# More efficient way of joining a tuple?

Tags: python, string

Is there a more efficient way of joining a tuple? since my rx gives me a tuple? 
Moreover c is '7:30' ' AM' at the end, and i need  '7:30 AM'

```
import re

rx = r"(?i)\b(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?:-\d{1,2}:\d{2})?(\s*[pa]m)\b"
s = "ankkjdf 7:30-8:30 AM dds "

matches = re.findall(rx, s)

m=str(matches)

a =''.join(m[2:8])
b= ''.join(m[9:15])

c = "".join(a + b)

print(c)
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have other issues if you get `s = "ankkjdf 11:30-1:30 PM dds"`, because I doubt `11:30 PM` is what you'll want as the result.

Comment: That is the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = r"(?i)\b(\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?:-\d{1,2}:\d{2})?(\s*[pa]m)\b"
>>> s = "ankkjdf 7:30-8:30 AM dds "
>>> matches = re.findall(rx, s)
>>> matches
[('7:30', ' AM')]
>>> [ "".join(x) for x in matches]
['7:30 AM']
>>>
```

or

```
>>> "".join(matches[0])
'7:30 AM'
>>>
```

or directly from the source

```
>>> [ "".join(x) for x in re.findall(rx, s)]
['7:30 AM']
>>> "".join( re.findall(rx, s)[0] )
'7:30 AM'
>>>
```

there is no reason to do `m=str(matches)`, just fuse together what you get in whatever way you want...

---

with the latest example

```
>>> test="Join us for a guided tour of the Campus given by Admissions staff. The tour will take place from 1:15-2:00 PM EST and leaves from the Admissions Office."
>>> [ "".join(x) for x in re.findall(rx, test)]
['1:15 PM']
>>> "".join( re.findall(rx, test)[0] )
'1:15 PM'
>>>
```

Comment: "Join us for a guided tour of the Campus given by Admissions staff. The tour will take place from 1:15-2:00 PM EST and leaves from the Admissions Office."  I am scraping data so something might be happening?

Comment: you must be using it in the wrong way, I get the expected result, check the updated...

Comment: You were right, sorry. One last thing.. I need the value as a string but the value I am getting is in [ ]: I am transforming it into a string and then replacing the square brackets. str(x).replace("[]",""). Is there a better way to do this? (replacing the brackets doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: well, how about using one of the other examples? like the ones that give you a singular string instead of a list of strings, you know like the very last example...

Comment: The last one works normally but when I use it to scrape the information I get this mistake. I am able to scrape the first event so the first date but nothing else. The error I get is : ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.hbs.edu/mba/admissions/admissions-events/Pages/default.aspx> (referer: None). I guess I'll use the other one.

Comment: This seems to work even if is not that efficient. Thank you for your help!  text = str(["".join(x) for x in re.findall(rx, s)]) /n

text=str(text[2:-2]).replace(" ","") /n

print(text)

Comment: uff, try with text= "".join( re.findall(rx, s)[0] ) \n print(text)

Comment: looks like you have some weird fixation with transforming everything to a string when there is no need to...

Comment: I need to transform it into a string to pass it into date time. I need date time so that I can store the events chronologically. I am open to suggestions if you have a better way of doing this. Because having to manually adjust my filters for each website I am scraping and it is annoying.

Comment: ok, but `"".join( re.findall(rx, s)[0] )` is already a String, (that for the last example is exactly `'1:15 PM'`), that is the version you should be using, and there no further need to use `str` on it, if more processing is needed do it directly to it. But instead you choose the other version that result in a List of strings